# Sorting Multidimensional array with multiple value in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

**I want to sort  array by value P if two P are same then sort by PD if two PD is same then sort by PF same as PA.**  
How i achieve this?

I have Multidimensional array In PHP Like

PHP:

```
$abc = array(
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'abc','overall' => array('MP' => '2','W'=> '2','L' => '0','D'=> '0','PF' => '2904','PA' => '1932','PD' => '972','P' => '6')),
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'abc','overall' => array('MP' => '2','W'=> '1','L' => '1','D'=> '0','PF' => '2320','PA' => '1974','PD' => '346','P' => '3')),
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'abc','overall' => array('MP' => '2','W'=> '1','L' => '1','D'=> '0','PF' => '1620','PA' => '1824','PD' => '-204','P' => '3')),
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'abc','overall' => array('MP' => '2','W'=> '0','L' => '2','D'=> '0','PF' => '2200','PA' => '2300','PD' => '-100','P' => '0'))
);
```

HTML :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [overall] => Array
                (
                    [MP] => 2
                    [W] => 0
                    [L] => 2
                    [D] => 0
                    [PF] => 2200
                    [PA] => 2300
                    [PD] => -100
                    [P] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [overall] => Array
                (
                    [MP] => 2
                    [W] => 1
                    [L] => 1
                    [D] => 0
                    [PF] => 2320
                    [PA] => 1974
                    [PD] => 346
                    [P] => 3
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [overall] => Array
                (
                    [MP] => 2
                    [W] => 1
                    [L] => 1
                    [D] => 0
                    [PF] => 1620
                    [PA] => 1824
                    [PD] => -204
                    [P] => 3
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [overall] => Array
                (
                    [MP] => 2
                    [W] => 2
                    [L] => 0
                    [D] => 0
                    [PF] => 2904
                    [PA] => 1932
                    [PD] => 972
                    [P] => 6
                )

        )

)
```

Want similar like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [overall] => Array
                (
                    [MP] => 2
                    [W] => 2
                    [L] => 0
                    [D] => 0
                    [PF] => 2904
                    [PA] => 1932
                    [PD] => 972
                    [P] => 6
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [overall] => Array
                (
                    [MP] => 2
                    [W] => 1
                    [L] => 1
                    [D] => 0
                    [PF] => 2320
                    [PA] => 1974
                    [PD] => 346
                    [P] => 3
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [overall] => Array
                (
                    [MP] => 2
                    [W] => 1
                    [L] => 1
                    [D] => 0
                    [PF] => 1620
                    [PA] => 1824
                    [PD] => -204
                    [P] => 3
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [overall] => Array
                (
                    [MP] => 2
                    [W] => 0
                    [L] => 2
                    [D] => 0
                    [PF] => 2200
                    [PA] => 2300
                    [PD] => -100
                    [P] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried like this.

```
    $memberArray1 = usort($memberArray, function($a, $b) {
        return  $b['overall']['P'] - $a['overall']['P'];
    });
    $memberArray1 = usort($memberArray, function($a, $b) {
        return  $b['overall']['PD'] - $a['overall']['PD'];
    });
```

But the issue is when i sort like P then it works but after when i sort like PD then it sort by PD not like P.

Comment: Post your attempts. What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `uasort` along with `rsort` as

```
uasort($abc,function($a,$b){
    $c = $a['P'] - $b['P'];
    $c .= $a['PD'] - $b['PD'];
    $c .= $a['PF'] - $b['PF'];
    $c .= $a['PA'] - $b['PA'];
    return $c;
});
array_reverse($abc);
print_r($abc);
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/424254)

Comment: yup it works!!!!
Thanks

Comment: @NarendraSisodia Your function may generate Undefined index warnings. Also if you reverse '$a' and '$b` in your subtraction there is no need for `rsort`.

Comment: Doing an `rsort` after a `uasort` should just invalidate the `uasort`. If you want to reverse the direction, just to `array_reverse`, or better, reverse `$a` and `$b` inside the comparison function.

Comment: Yep I know that I can simply reverse `$a` and `$b` but didn't worked but it seems `array_reverse` is better option @deceze

Comment: @Ishan Be advised that this does *not* work!

Comment: @deceze I've updated my answer as per `array_reverse`. If my answer is not the correct one I'm ready to delete it too

Comment: Can you make an update of my answer @deceze